# How to setup O365 made possible login with thephpleague/oauth2-client and working with msgraph-sdk-php?

Tags: php, laravel, azure, oauth-2.0, office365

I try to implement a php client, access a mailbox of a user with graph api. Because it's a background service, which should fetching specific mails attachment, it must run with grant type password. 
So far, I got it really easy working make a login with thephpleague/oauth2-client and grant type client_credentials:

```
    $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => '...',
      'clientSecret'            => '...',
      'redirectUri'             => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient',
      'urlAuthorize'            => null,
      'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/token?api-version=1.0',
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
    ]);

    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('client_credentials');
```

Now I try it with grant type password, but it fails:

```
    $provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
      'clientId'                => '...',
      'clientSecret'            => '...',
      'redirectUri'             => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient',
      'urlAuthorize'            => null,
      'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../oauth2/token?api-version=1.0',
      'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
    ]);

    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('password', [
      'username'                => '...',
      'password'                => '...',
    ]);
```

Response I get: `invalid_request`. Google that error, I come to https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow which tells me, I should fix my request.

Now... somehow it's hard, finding a) a ressource telling which urls are right and b) finding a tutorial, tell how I add right a app so I can get it working (maybe also a result, because the o365 layout changes fast...)

Does anyone have a idea, what the right parameters are and what I must do in the Azure Active Directory Admin Center so its working?

My goal is "only", access a users mailbox and get attachments from existing mails. I think, when I can authenticate successfully, all other things are easy (hope so).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official tutorial: [Authenticate with the Microsoft Graph service](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php#authenticate-with-the-microsoft-graph-service).

To authenticate as an application you can use the [Guzzle HTTP client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), which comes preinstalled with this library, for example like this:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$tenantId = 'your_tenanet_id, e4c9ab4e-****-****-****-230ba2a757fb';
$clientId = 'your_app_id_registered_in_portal, dc175b96-****-****-****-ea03e56da5e7';
$clientSecret = 'app_key_generated_in_portal, /pGggH************************Zr732';
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/token';

$user_token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'resource' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/',
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'your_user_id, jack@***.onmcirosoft.com', 
        'password' => 'your_password'
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$user_accessToken = $user_token->access_token;

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($user_accessToken );

$response = $graph->createRequest('Get','/me/messages')
    ->setReturnType(Model\Message::class)
    ->execute();

?>
```

Note that the resource should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/`